# How i should set parameters of Scrypt hashing function so I can get a duration of hash processing about 250 ms?

Tags: authentication, hash, scrypt

I whant to hashing a password with SCrypto hashing function but if i will to use a default parameters i get hashing duration about 5-6 seconds. How i can set parameters so i get duration less then 1 second (better 250 ms)

SCrypt.scrypt(pass, salt, n, r, p, length)

default Scrypt(pass, salt, 16384, 8, 1, length)

Answer (score 1):

The answer will be highly dependent on your device. The time taken will be roughly proportional to N * r, though, so if it's currently taking 6 seconds, N / 8 (because it's a power of 2) should get you under 1 second, and N / 32 should get you to ~250 ms.

But be careful, because values so small reduce the overall security of the function, and it may even become worse than tried-and-true methods like bcrypt: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/03/why-i-dont-recommend-scrypt.html

Also note the recommendation not to use Scrypt as a password hashing function (for storage), but as a key derivation function (what it was designed for), where the resulting key isn't stored.